# Can anyone understand/explain this String Extension?

Tags: c#, string

We have a file called "StringExtensions" which works as a "class" which can be used for multiple datasets/models I assume.

Can anyone help understand what this `ToSafeString` does to a string?

```
public static string ToSafeString(this object source)
{
    return source?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: It prevents an *NullReferenceException* if you write code like 
`object test = null;`
`Console.WriteLine(test.ToSafeString());`

Answer (score 9):

It checks if the object is not null with `source?`. If it is not `null`, then `ToString()` is called and the result is returned. If it is `null`, then`string.Empty` returned.

It uses [(.?) null conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and [(??) null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operators.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly source?. checks to see if the object being passed in is null, if it is that entire portion `(source?.ToString())` will return null and due to the `?.` operator the `.ToString()` does not get evaluated. This operator is short hand and is equivalent to writing:

```
if(source != null) {
  return source.ToString();
} else {
 return null;
}
```

Next, the null coalescing operator ( `??` ) kicks in and it will return string.Empty instead of just a null if either source or the return from `.ToString()` was null.

If called with `null` it will return `string.Empty`

If called on an object that has a `.ToString()` method that returns `null`, it will also return `string.Empty`

If called with an object that has a value to return from `.ToString()` it will return that value.